# How to use Chrome extension(or Firefox add-on) to receive DNS records that both of "Operation system DNS" and "DNS over HTTPS server"?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, https, dns, firefox-addon

I am trying to use Chrome extension(or Firefox add-on) to detect "DNS spoofing" and notify the user by extension icon. The rule is:

- Green extension icon = Web site IP that received from OS DNS & DNS
  over HTTPS server are same.
- Yellow extension icon = Web site IP that received from OS DNS & DNS
  over HTTPS server are different. But Web site IP that received from
  OS DNS is private
- Red extension icon = Web site IP that received from OS DNS & DNS
  over HTTPS server are different.

As I know, there are two famous DNS over HTTPS servers in the world (one is Google, another one is Cloudflare), I choice Cloudflare without reason ^_^

How to coding below function?

1. Ask operation system's DNS to get an IP (I have already done in https://github.com/kevinbolton/DNSOverHTTPS/tree/master/FirefoxAddOn)
2. Use HTTPS protocol to ask DNS over HTTPS server to get an IP
3. Change extension icon by rules.

Comment: Your question is far too broad. You will need to show what you have tried already to get some specific help. I also fail to see what you want to achieve. Is 2) to happen only if 1) fails or always? If always, 1) why and 2) what do you do if there is a mismatch. Also why targeting specifically CloudFlare DoH?

Comment: Note that if the DoH client does not check certificates and/or do pinning, it will be vulnerable to spoofing as well. Latest version of Firefox include a DoH client by default

Comment: @PatrickMevzek
You are right.
I have enabled Firefox DoH client(network.trr.mode = 2, network.trr.uri = https://mozilla.cloudflare-dns.com/dns-query), but It will timeout when browse to office mail server(Firefox connect to public IP not private IP) 
So I am trying to using HTTPS protocol to use HoD function